# Rails create defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application I would like to sell to potential clients. When I deploy and install this application on their server I would like to have something that automatically creates some demo data.

Is there a way to do this? Or would that be done with seeds?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use rails scaffold to generate resources and yes you can use seeds to create demo data in your db.

You add any data that needs creating in your seeds.rb file and execute them using `bundle exec rake db:seed`.
[see here for some examples on how to do it](http://www.petermac.com/seeding-your-rails-database/)